# How to download pdf file from mapfish print in geoserver implementation using php?

Tags: php, pdf, printing

I receive following response from POST request to API provided by geoserver for print module:

[image: response from post request]

But I am getting errors on the downloaded file however direct post request from POSTMAN seems to work.

```
$response = $client->request('POST','http://valid_url:8080/geoserver/pdf/print.pdf', [
    'json'=>["all required param are passed here"]]);
```

I need solution to download pdf file obtained from request or convert it into readable format or generate valid pdf file to be downloaded.

Comment: what sort of errors are you getting? that looks like a pdf file coming back

Comment: I want to download the received pdf file, it does return a pdf file but I am unable to make it downloadable for a client from PHP, I am confused if I need to process and send the response to the client-side or direct transfer of response from PHP to the client, however direct transfer of response using ajax does not seem to work, I must be missing some conversion to be done it middle, but unable to figure out how